# Bash command to check if file exists doesn't work though the file name is matching

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, scripting

I have the following script to connect to a SFTP server and delete a file if it matches the name. But though the file with the matching name is there in the server, the script fails to go into the -f check block and hence not deleting the file. What am I doing wrong here? Below is my script.

```
readarray partners < fileName.txt

for i in "${partners[@]}"
do
  file=`echo "ls" | sftp -i myKey myUser@myIP:${i} | grep "_Name_file_20181024"`
  echo $i
  echo $file

  if [[ -f $file ]]; then
    echo "********"
    delete=`echo "rm $file" | sftp -i myKey myUser@myIP:${i}`
    echo "********"
    echo $delete
  fi


done
```

I'm running this in my Mac. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f` checks if a file exists **on your machine**.
I guess you can check if the file string is nonempty:

```
if [ -n "$file" ]; then
```

But checking the result of grep would be more desirable:

```
if echo "ls" | sftp -i myKey "myUser@myIP:$i" | grep -q "_Name_file_20181024"; then
```

Remainders:

- backticks ` are deprecated. Use `$( ... )` for command substitution, which allows for nesting (and is more readable).
- Always quote your variables. What if the filename has spaces?
- `sftp` is just `ssh` but only file transfer.
- Don't parse `ls` output. It's bad. `ls` is for nice formatted output.

I would do it like this, in one single pass:

```
<fileName.txt xargs ssh -i myKey "myUser@myIP" rm -v -f
```

The `xargs` will transform each line from `fileName.txt` as separate argument. Alternatively you can `readarray partners < fileName.txt` and `ssh .... rm -v -f "${partners[@]}"` if you don't have xargs. The `ssh` will run once (thus it will be very fast). If you just check if the file exists and then remove it, why check at all, if the end result is nonexistent file? The `-f` option will make `rm` not fail in case the removed file does not exists and `-v` will print if the file was removed (thus you will know which files were removed).

Or if you have to sftp, probably this would work:

```
echo "rm -v -f $(<fileName.txt xargs printf "%q ")" |
sftp -i myKey myUser@myIP
```

but I am not sure about special characters in filenames, so I think this would need some tweaking.

If you want to filter from the list nonexistent files, I would do:

```
<fileName.txt ssh -i myKey "myUser@myIP" 'while IFS= read -r file; do [ -f "$file" ] && echo "$file"; done'
```

ie. The `while IFS= read -r` part is executed remotely, thus files are checked for existence on the remove server. It is faster the execute a single ssh connection for all the work, then doing separate ssh connections for single files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that the if statement looks for the file on your mac, not on the server?

Do you maybe want to check if the file variable is empty?   `if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then`